# How to use AMQP instead of JMS with Ehcache?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, ehcache, amqp

Ehcache supports OpenMQ and ActiveMQ natively and uses JMS for synchronization. 
Is it possible to use RabbitMQ with AMQP instead ?

I am aware of https://github.com/jamescarr/ehcache-amqpreplication/pull/2 project but it seems to be old and not used by larger community.

Is there an alternative? What exactly must be done to use AMQP and RabbitMQ in Ehcache?

Comment: Qpid is another alternative.